# Why are WDT words being marked as a sentence subject by dependency parsing?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to report the subject of each sentence; and also extract all its modifiers. (E.g. "Donald Trump" not just "Trump"; "(The) average remaining lease term" not just "term".)

Here is my test code:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def handle(doc):
    for sent in doc.sents:
        shownSentence = False
        for token in sent:
            if(token.dep_=="nsubj"):
                if(not shownSentence):
                    print("----------")
                    print(sent)
                    shownSentence = True
                print("{0}/{1}".format(token.text, token.tag_))
                print([ [t,t.tag_] for t in token.children])

handle(nlp('Donald Trump, legend in his own lifetime, said: "This transaction is a continuation of our main strategy to invest in assets which offer growth potential and that are coloured pink." The average remaining lease term is six years, and Laura Palmer was killed by Bob. Trump added he will sell up soon.'))
```

The output is below. I'm wondering why I get "which/WDT" as a subject? Is it just model noise, or is it considered correct behaviour?  (Incidentally, in my real sentence, which had the same structure, I also got "that/WDT" being marked as a subject.) (**UPDATE:** If I switch to 'en_core_web_md' then I *do* get "that/WDT" for my Trump example; that is the only difference switching from the small to the medium model makes.)

I can easily filter them out by looking at `tag_`; I'm more interested in the underlying reason.

(**UPDATE:** Incidentally, "Laura Palmer" doesn't get pulled out as a subject by this code, as the `dep_` value is "nsubjpass", not "nsubj".)

```
----------
Donald Trump, legend in his own lifetime, said: "This transaction is a continuation of our main strategy to invest in assets which offer growth potential and that are coloured pink."
Trump/NNP
[[Donald, 'NNP'], [,, ','], [legend, 'NN'], [,, ',']]
transaction/NN
[[This, 'DT']]
which/WDT
[]
----------
The average remaining lease term is six years, and Laura Palmer was killed by Bob.
term/NN
[[The, 'DT'], [average, 'JJ'], [remaining, 'JJ'], [lease, 'NN']]
----------
Trump added he will sell up soon.
Trump/NNP
[]
he/PRP
[]
```

(By the way, the bigger picture: pronoun resolution. I want to turn PRPs into the text they refer to.)